# Fast algorithm for computing certain signal transformations

Tags: algorithms, fourier-analysis, computational-complexity, signal-analysis

Let $f,g,h:\mathbb Z\to\mathbb C$ supported on $[-n,n]$.  For $\tau\in \mathbb Z$, let $\operatorname{sh}_\tau f$ be the shift of $f$ by $\tau$ (i.e. $(\operatorname{sh}_\tau f)(t) = f(t-\tau)$). Define $$k(\tau)=\lVert((\operatorname{sh}_\tau f) \cdot g)*h\rVert_2.$$
Here  $*$ stands for convolution and $\cdot$ stands for the value-wise product.

I am looking for a fast way to compute $k(\tau)$ for all relevant $\tau$ (say $\tau \in [-2n,2n]$).

By fast I mean asymptotically faster than $n^2$, preferably something around $n \ln^k n$.
One can use the following assumptions:

1. $g$, $h$ are fixed functions and one can do a reasonable amount (say $n^3$) of preprocessing on them. Then one has to compute $k(\tau)$ for many different $f$-s.
2. One can assume that $h$ is a normal distribution.

Comment: I think it may help if you add some more details, such as the definition of "*" (so sort of convolution?), what you mean by the product of functions sh(f) and g, what you mean by "all relevant tau", etc. If this messes up the presentation, you may wish to add some of these clarifications at the end of the question.

Comment: Is the shift cyclic (with wrap-around) or does it translate the function to be supported on $[-n+\tau,n+\tau]$?

Comment: Is [Convolution - Discrete Convolution - Fast convolution algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Fast_convolution_algorithms) relevant?